# beautiful soup parse table columns and stripping newlines

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using the following code to cycle through each row and column of an html table

```
data = []
table = page.find('table', attrs={'class':'table table-no-border table-hover table-striped keyword_result_table'})
table_body = table.find('tbody')

rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) # Get rid of empty values
```

This table column is giving me a few

```
    <td class="keyword">
     <span class="is_in_saved_list" id="is_in_saved_list_81864060">
     </span>
     <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <b>
       what
      </b>
      <b>
       is
      </b>
      <b>
       in
      </b>
      <b>
       house
      </b>
      <b>
       paint
      </b>
     </a>
    </td>
```

The output is coming out as

['what\n              \n\n               is\n              \n\n               in\n              \n\n               house\n              \n\n               paint', '5756', '979', '2', 'Great', '89', '.com\n             \n\n              .net\n             \n\n              .org']

On the console and on the prompt screen here, there seems to be tab spaces but they are not displaying in the post. I have tried .rstrip() after strip() but no change. Is there a way to grab only the text content that the  link is attached to?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.stripped_strings` to get the text without any spaces/tabs.

Here is the code:

```py
import bs4 as bs

s = """
 <td class="keyword">
     <span class="is_in_saved_list" id="is_in_saved_list_81864060">
     </span>
     <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <b>
       what
      </b>
      <b>
       is
      </b>
      <b>
       in
      </b>
      <b>
       house
      </b>
      <b>
       paint
      </b>
     </a>
    </td>
    """
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
t = soup.find('td')
print(list(t.stripped_strings))
```

```
['what', 'is', 'in', 'house', 'paint']
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try remove '\n' from the strings?

```
s = 'what\n \n\n is\n \n\n in\n \n\n house\n \n\n paint'
s.replace('\n', '')
'what  is  in  house  paint'
```